Is “Linear Light”, which is often used in material nodes, necessary?
I have been learning by watching various how to videos.
What you often see in any material node video is
The method is to combine the noise texture and color mix node (linear light) shown in the image below, and then connect it to the vector input of some texture node.
I'm wondering if this is actually really necessary.
Is there something that cannot be expressed without using this combination of nodes?
I believe that a wide variety of patterns can be created purely by combining texture nodes.
However, I don't think it's wrong to use it to improve the quality of details, considering how often other creators use it, just because I don't realize it.
I would be very happy if someone could specifically verbalize and visualize this.


I tried to answer the question and realized it makes no sense at all. Necessary for what? For making procedural textures? Obviously, no. For adding detail? No, there are other ways. Is it needed? Yes, it's useful. This is kind of obvious, so what is this question about?

"What you often see..." - so you know it's only "often", but not always, so you know it's not necessary.

The attached image shows the skin created, but I also created the skin using my own workflow.
At that time, I felt that there was no intuitive difference between not doing the liner path process and doing it.
What do you mean by convenience? Does it mean that some processes can be reduced?

If I understand you correctly, what you are asking is "is it necessary to use a noise texture to get this pattern or can I replace it with a texture?". - In the video this shader is (almost) all procedural, but you can bake the textures and replace the noise textures.

@vectorman The problem is we have to watch the video to see the difference, is the top node tree yours and the bottom is the original?

@KISKAart Baking and replacing means that perhaps mixing other vectors with this lireat path is expressing the noise pattern of the noise texture differently.
This is only for the purpose of increasing the types of noise patterns of noise texture.
Is it okay to understand that there is no meaning beyond that or anything else?
Then everything will be clear.

@KISKAart Sorry for the mistake.
The attached image is the node settings of the video host.

@vectorman Answer to the title: Linear light is just a blend mode, that's it, you can change it to get different effects, I thought you actually repeated the steps shown in the video, but you just took the screenshot.

Creating procedural textures involves artistic aspect. There are no rigid rules, just tools to achieve something. It makes no sense to ask if something is "necessary" in general. The question should be if it's necessary for you to achieve something that you judge as visually acceptable to your purpose. That depends on your situation and personal judgment. This is not something that someone else can answer for you.
